# JSF Polymorphic input

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component, composite-component

I'm trying to build a composite component to wrap input.
The problem is that I need to read from a DB the labels and the input types.

Here is what I've done:

field.java (pojo containing field label, type, required or not....

```
public class Field {
    private String label;
    private char type; // a = alphanumeric, t = textarea, ...

    ...
}
```

myField.xhtml (main composite compontent)

```
<cc:interface componentType="myField">
    <cc:attribute name="fieldKey" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <label id="label">#{myField.field.label}</label>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

MyField.java (backing component of composite field)

```
@FacesComponent(value = "myField")
public class MyField extends UINamingContainer {
    private Field field;

    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext ctx){
        field = lookupField(getAttributes().get("fieldKey")) ; // gets the field calling a view scoped bean which lookups on a db thrugh an ejb

        // PSEUDO CODE STARTS HERE
        if (field.getType() == 't'){
            // Replace input text with a textarea
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This kind of structure (fields type and labels stored in a db) is a "legacy" system and can't be changed.

First problem: when should fields be loaded? I've resolved this issue registering a custom view scoped bean, which holdes the list of of fields for the current view, as a preRenderView Listener and it seems to work.

Second problem (the real one): how can I change the inputText with another kind of UIInput ? I've already tried putting all types of UIInput (inputText, inputSecret, inputTextarea, select....) in the composite with different "rendered" conditions but I don't like this approach and it seems that having multiple components binded to the same bean property could bring problems.

Another approach I'v tried is replacing the inputText in the composite xhtml with a generic ui:component binding a corresponding UIInput in the MyField component:

myField.xhtml

```
<label id="label">#{myField.field.label}</label>
<ui:component binding="#{myField.input} />
```

MyField.java

```
@FacesComponent(value = "myField")
public class MyField extends UINamingContainer {
    private UIInput input; // At runtime this get instatiated with the correct subclass
    private Field field;
    ...
}
```

the problem here is that the "getter" of the UIInput is called before the preRenderView which loads fields definitions so I can't know which knid of Input to instantiate.

The last thing that comes in my mind is to create another custom component which extends UIInput with a custom renderer which renders an input field or a textarea or so on...

What's the "JSF correct approach" to this problem?

Thanks for the support